# Javascript inheritance by two subclases

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```js
var first = function() {
  this.loc = '1';
  this.test = function() {
    console.log('first ' + this.loc);
  }
}

var second = function() {
  var me = this;

  this.loc = '2';
  this.test = function() {
    console.log('second ' + this.loc);
    Object.getPrototypeOf(me).test.call(me);
  }
}

second.prototype = new first();

var third = function() {
  var me = this;

  this.loc = '3';
  this.test = function() {
    console.log('third ' + this.loc);
    Object.getPrototypeOf(me).test.call(me);
  }
}

third.prototype = new second();

var t = new third();
t.test();
```

It will output:

```
third 3
second 3
first 2
```

How can I make it output:

```
third 3
second 3
first 3
```

So I want to override first class loc value with the last inherited class.

Comment: it's interesting to note that using ES6 semantics we see expected behaviour: https://repl.it/EmmE/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `thisArg`(signature `fun.call(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])`) for the `second` object function call from `me` to `this`:

```
...
var second = function() {
    var me = this;

    this.loc = '2';
    this.test = function() {
        console.log('second ' + this.loc);
        Object.getPrototypeOf(me).test.call(this); // <--
    }
}
...
```

***How it goes:***

at first time, `test()` function is called upon `third` instance outputting `"third 3"`

then, `test` function is called from the `second` instance(being a `third` prototype) upon the same `third` instance by `Object.getPrototypeOf(me).test.call(me);`

when `test` function is executing `this` keyword should point to the `third` instance and be passed to further `test()` call

Answer (score 0):

the `this` pointer of `second` actually is `third.prototype`. so set the `loc` property of `second` (`third.prototype`)

```js
var first = function() {
  this.loc = '1';
  this.test = function() {
    console.log('first ' + this.loc);
  }
}

var second = function() {
  var me = this;

  this.loc = '2';
  this.test = function() {
    console.log('second ' + this.loc);
    Object.getPrototypeOf(me).test.call(me);
  }
}

second.prototype = new first();

var third = function() {
  var me = this;

  this.loc = '3';
  this.test = function() {
    console.log('third ' + this.loc);
    Object.getPrototypeOf(me).test.call(me);
  }
}

third.prototype = new second();
third.prototype.loc = 3;

var t = new third();
t.test();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing some interesting things with the inheritance by mixing prototype and this.x assignments. I wonder it the following snipset will do what you want instead:

```
var first = function( num ){
    this.num = num;
}

first.prototype.test = function(){ console.log("value " + this.num); }

// test it
var x = new first(10);
x.test();

var second = function( ){
  first.apply(this, arguments);
}
second.prototype = new first();
second.prototype.test2 = function(){ console.log("second " + this.num) };

// test it
var y = new second( 20 );
y.test()

var third = function( ){
  second.apply(this, arguments);
}
third.prototype = new second();
second.prototype.test3 = function(){ console.log("third " + this.num) };

// test it
var z = new third( 30 );
z.test()
z.test2()
z.test3()
```